# Csv bounded source with a custom line Delimitter

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I want to read a csv file with a line Delimiter other than the default line delimiter. Each csv record spans multiple lines so the TextIO.Read does not suffice.

Should I extend the FileBasedSource or is there any existing CsvBasedSource (with a custom line/fields delimiter).

I was looking in to the splitIntoBundles() api, the XmlSource did not override the isSplittable() and so it can be split in to bundles and was wondering how the XmlSource handles this because the split can happen at the middle of a <record> as the split is happening based on the desiredBundleSize only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct that this will need a custom FileBasedSource implementation to work.  Regarding XMLSource, record and root element names have to be unique (i.e. no other elements can have those names).  We'll update the documentation to reflect that, and look at improving this in the future.

Comment: Thank you. I did a fun implementation to convert the csv bytes underneath to xml and delegated the parsing to XmlSource. https://github.com/ksenji/flink-exercises/blob/master/src/main/java/da/exercises/googledataflow/CsvSource.java

Comment: Nice!  Glad you're up and running.